# WebAPI Token Authorization Bearer Getting Error: The operation was canceled

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, access-token

I am working on .NET Core WebAPI (Core 3.1) project where I have to make call to outside third party API's using OAuth2 Toekn based implementation.

Basically it is 2-Step process. First step is to get Token using Token API Call and then make call to Export API by passing this Token-AccessCode and Input JSON.

I am sucessfully able to get Token using below API Controller Code, but second API call(Export API Method) is throwing error.
Where as when i tested in Postman using Bearer Authorization, it worked fine.

Step(1) In Postman, Authorization tab is set to "No Auth".

Step(2) Header Tab has two settings as below (Authorization and Content-Type).

[image]

Step(3) From Body Tab, I am sending below JSON.

```
{
"oneOf": {
"schedule_date": "08/05/2020",
"request_date": null
},
"start_time": "",
"end_time": "",
"order_number": "",
"status": ""
}
```

After the above 3 settings, when i call POST method in Postman, it is returning response.
Where as below APICode is throwing error at Line **exportClient.PostAsync()** call.

**Error:**
**Exception:**The operation was canceled.
**InnerException:** Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..

What am i doing wrong?
Appreciate your resposes.

***This is the APIController Code:***

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("PullOrders")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PullOrders(
    )
    {
        try
        {
            var token = await GetElibilityToken();
            string exportUrl = "https://XXXXXXX.com/api/v1/export";
            var exportClient = new HttpClient();

            //exportClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken);
            exportClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
            exportClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var oneData = new OneOf() { schedule_date = "08/05/2020" };
            var orderReq = new PullOrderInputRequest() { oneOf = oneData };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderReq, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(json);

            HttpResponseMessage orderResponse = await **exportClient.PostAsync**(exportUrl, stringContent);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return Ok();

    }

    private static async Task<Token> GetElibilityToken()
    {
        var tokenClient = new HttpClient();
        string baseAddress = @"https:// XXXXXXX/api/v1/oauth2/token";

        string grant_type = "client_credentials";
        string client_id = " XXXXXXX";
        string client_secret = " XXXXXXXXXXXXXX ";

        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type", grant_type},
                {"client_id", client_id},
                {"client_secret", client_secret},
            };

        HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await tokenClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
        var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Token tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonContent);
        return tok;
    }

    internal class Token
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: When I google "unable to read data from the transport connection The I/O operation has been aborted because" I get a lot of good results. Have you tried any of those solutions?

Comment: I tried using RestSharp. Now at least I am getting "UnAuthorised Error" with this code:

var client = new RestClient("https://XXXXXXX.com/api/v1/export");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(token.AccessToken)));
    request.AddJsonBody(stringContent); 
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);